# I get npm run dev and npm run build errors in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, vue.js, nuxt.js

Developed on Mac.

Start with the following command:

`vue init nuxt / express myproject`

After development, prepare to build on the real server. (ubuntu)
The configuration of the real server is as follows.

`├── @ nuxtjs / axios @ 4.4.0
├── alertify.js@1.0.12
├── axios@0.16.2
├── babel-polyfill@6.26.0
├── body-parser@1.18.2
├── bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2
├── connect-redis@3.3.2
├── cookie-parser@1.4.3
├── cross-env@5.1.0
├── express@4.16.2
├── express-session@1.15.6
├── fs@0.0.1-security
├── jquery@3.2.1
├── lodash@4.17.4
├── moment@2.19.1
├── node@8.3.0
├── nuxt@1.0.0-rc9
├── passport@0.4.0
├── passport-local@1.0.0
├── pg-promise@7.0.2
├── popper.js@1.12.5
├── redis@2.8.0
├── source-map-support@0.4.18
├── winston@2.4.0
└── winston-daily-rotate-file@1.7.2`

Enter the command.

`npm run dev`

[image]

This time, type the following command.

`npm run build`

[image]

**All errors such as images are generated.**

**There was no problem when developing on the local server.**

**Why do I get an error?**

Comment: Do you forget to install eslint-loader?

Comment: i installed the module and saw the same error.

Comment: the error is: eslint-loader module?

Comment: Why do I get an error when I try to install it? I did **npm run build** after **npm install --save-dev eslint-loader**.

Comment: solved it. problem is NODE_ENV. Thanks.

Comment: @hyeokluv how did you fix it with NODE_ENV ? I tried `export NODE_ENV=production` but it's still not working